# How to iterate with click event through Array of divs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick

I want text parts to appear, and disappear, on click.

Before the first click you can only see the banner, and no verses yet; on the first click the first verse appears, on second click the second verse appears in place of the first, and so on.

I am trying to achieve this with hiding the elements, placing them in an array, and let them display when the number of times the function gets called fits the index of the verse.

I am new to JavaScript, and don't understand the exceptions thrown. If i try to inspect my code online, I get this Exception when O try to call the function by clicking on the website:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

This is my code so far:

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".banner")
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

const verse1 = document.querySelector(".verse1")
const verse2 = document.querySelector(".verse2")
const verse3 = document.querySelector(".verse3")
const verse4 = document.querySelector(".verse4")
const verse5 = document.querySelector(".verse5")
const verses = [verse1, verse2, verse3, verse4, verse5]
let versesLength = verses.length;

function myFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < versesLength; i++) {
    text.innerHTML = verses[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <img src="files/SomeLogo.jpg" alt="We are still building on our Website:-)">
</div>

<div id="verses">
  <div class="verse1" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="verse2" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum2</div>
  <div class="verse3" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum3</div>
  <div class="verse4" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum4</div>
  <div class="verse5" style="display: none">Lorem Ipsum5</div>
</div>
```

I am stuck, and clicked through similar questions for the last hours. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without changing anything in the HTML, you can do something like this in javascript

```
const text = document.querySelector(".banner")
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

let verses = document.querySelector("#verses").children
let count = 0
function myFunction() {
  Array.from(verses).forEach(el=> el.style.display="none")
  if(count < verses.length){
    verses[count].style.display = 'block'
    count ++
    if(count===verses.length) count =0
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this function part of the innerHTML of the text constant? So the banner div disappears and the text elements appear instead?

Comment: @maybe_JPEG Please add this to your question so others can show you their way, too.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it:

```js
const verses = document.querySelectorAll('.verse');
const banner = document.querySelector('.banner');

const length = verses.length;
let counter = 0;

document.onclick = () => {
  if (counter === 0) banner.classList.add('hide');
  if (counter >= length) return;
  verses[counter].classList.add('show');
  if (verses[counter - 1]) verses[counter - 1].classList.remove('show');
  counter++;
};
```

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <img
        src="files/SomeLogo.jpg"
        alt="We are still building on our Website:-)"
      />
    </div>
    <div id="verses">
      <div class="verse1 verse hide">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="verse2 verse hide">Lorem Ipsum2</div>
      <div class="verse3 verse hide">Lorem Ipsum3</div>
      <div class="verse4 verse hide">Lorem Ipsum4</div>
      <div class="verse5 verse hide">Lorem Ipsum5</div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much, also pushing the script tag down to the end of the code finally made something happen on my end.

Comment: @Andy, yeah sorry, I did not read accurately the requirements, updated the JS snippet accordingly. @maybe_JPEG Yes, if you want your script to have access to DOM you need to place selectors inside `DOMContentLoaded` eventListener, or you need to place the `<script>` tag at the bottom of body!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove the need for an array by giving all the verse elements the same class: `verse`. We can grab them with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
2. Add [a data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each verse to identify them.
3. In order to limit the number of global variables we can use a closure - in the `addEventListener` we call the `handleClick` function which initialises the count, and then returns a function that will be assigned to the listener. This is [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It maintains a copy of its outer lexical environment (ie variables) that it can use when it's returned.

```js
// Cache the elements with the verse class
const banner = document.querySelector('.banner');
const verses = document.querySelectorAll('.verse');

// Call `handleClick` and assign the function it
// returns to the listener
document.addEventListener('click', handleClick());

function handleClick() {

  // Initialise `count`
  let count = 1;

  // Return a function that maintains a
  // copy of `count`
  return function () {

    // If the count is 5 or less
    if (count < verses.length + 1) {

      // Remove the banner
      if (count === 1) banner.remove();

      // Remove the previous verse
      if (count > 1) {
        const selector = `[data-id="${count - 1}"]`;
        const verse = document.querySelector(selector);
        verse.classList.remove('show');
      }

      // Get the new verse
      const selector = `[data-id="${count}"]`;
      const verse = document.querySelector(selector);

      // And show it
      verse.classList.add('show');

      // Increase the count
      ++count;

    }

  }

}
```

```css
.verse { display: none; }
.show { display: block; margin-top: 1em; padding: 0.5em; border: 1px solid #787878; }
[data-id="1"] { background-color: #efefef; } 
[data-id="2"] { background-color: #dfdfdf; } 
[data-id="3"] { background-color: #cfcfcf; } 
[data-id="4"] { background-color: #bfbfbf; } 
[data-id="5"] { background-color: #afafaf; }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x75/404082/ffffff&text=We+are+still+building+our+website" alt="We are still building on our Website:-)">
</div>

<div>
  <div data-id="1" class="verse">Lorem Ipsum 1</div>
  <div data-id="2" class="verse">Lorem Ipsum 2</div>
  <div data-id="3" class="verse">Lorem Ipsum 3</div>
  <div data-id="4" class="verse">Lorem Ipsum 4</div>
  <div data-id="5" class="verse">Lorem Ipsum 5</div>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0):

## Fixing the error

The "Cannot read properties of null" error occurs because you try to access the properties of null. Your array holds nulls because you queried for the elements before the browser has inserted them into its DOM.

The browser parses the HTML the same way you would read it: From left to right, and top to bottom.

If the browser encounters a regular `<script>` element, it halts parsing and first executes the JavaScript. Naturally, some elements may not yet be available in the DOM.

There are multiple ways to defer script execution:

- Add [attribute `defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) to `<script>`: Will execute once the DOM is fully built.
- Add [attribute `type="module"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) to `<script>`: Similar to `defer`, but will also make your code be treated as a [JS module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). This will also make your code run in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).
- Use JS [event `DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event): Similar to `defer`, but encapsulated in your JS-file.
- Use JS [event `load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event): Similar to `DOMContentLoaded`, but will additionally wait until *all* resources (e.g. images, videos) have loaded. **Prefer `DOMContentLoaded` if applicable.**
- Move `<script>` to the bottom of the HTML: Effectively like `defer`. Scripts with `defer` will still load after scripts at the bottom.

The simplest solution would be to use `defer`, as with it you wouldn't have to change your JS code:

```html
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
```

By the way: Don't be fooled by the StackOverflow snippets; when using the on-site snippets, the `<script>` for the code is moved to the bottom of the HTML!

## The feature!

### Variable lifetimes

Variables in JS only persist for as long as they are used.

Using a variable that is declared outside a function will create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) around your function and variable. That means, *that* variable will persist for as long as the function exists that uses it:

```js
let someVariable = 0;
function someFunction() {
  // `someVariable` is used, so it will persist across calls!
  return someVariable;
}
```

This means, to have the variable for "keeping track of what verse to show" persist, it has to be declared outside your function.

### Show and hide!

By calculating the previous verse's index with the index of the next-to-show verse, we only have to keep one counter. With two counters, they might get out of sync if we don't handle them correctly.

```js
let nextToShow = 0;
function showNextVerse() {
  const previousIndex = nextToShow - 1;
  // ...
  
  ++nextToShow; // Increase counter for next call
}
```

In our case, the user (or rather, their clicks) will play the role of the loop. They will cause our click handler (the function) to run occasionally, at which point we have to swap the verses.

Swapping the verses can be done in many ways, but we'll stick to your "inline style" way: (Final code)

```js
document.addEventListener("click", showNextVerse);

const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
const verses = document.getElementById("verses").children; // More on this later

let nextToShow = 0;
function showNextVerse() {
  const previousIndex = nextToShow - 1;
  
  // On every call, hide the banner
  banner.style.display = "none"; // Use `.style` instead of `.innerHTML` to preserve its HTML!
  
  // Hide previous if valid index
  if (previousIndex >= 0 && previousIndex < verses.length) {
    verses[previousIndex].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  // Show next if valid index
  if (nextToShow >= 0 && nextToShow < verses.length) {
    verses[nextToShow].style.display = "block";
  }
  
  ++nextToShow;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
  <img alt="We are still building on our Website:-)">
</div>

<div id="verses">
  <div style="display:none">Lorem Ipsum1</div>
  <div style="display:none">Lorem Ipsum2</div>
  <div style="display:none">Lorem Ipsum3</div>
  <div style="display:none">Lorem Ipsum4</div>
  <div style="display:none">Lorem Ipsum5</div>
</div>
```

## Improvements?!

There is no need for the variable `versesLength`; you can directly replace each of its occurences with `verses.length`. It doesn't improve on the original name, and is one more potential source for bugs if not synchronized with the original variable.

### Correctly use `class` and `id`

Currently, your verses use `class` as if it was `id`; they each use a different class. This is not wrong, but semantically I would use `id` for this purpose.

To use the `class` attribute effectively, you should give each verse the class `verse`. This way, you can select them more easily via JS (see next section).

### Easier getting of elements

As with everything in the coding world, there are many solutions to a problem. You solved getting the elements in a rather tedious way, but there are alternatives: (Non-exhaustive list)

- Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- Rename verses to use same class, and use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).
- Use [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children).

You may have already noticed how I get all the verses. In fact, `verses` (in the final code) doesn't even reference an array, but an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). It is very similar to an array, with the exception of it updating live to changes:

```js
const elementsWrapper = document.getElementById("elements");

const collection = elementsWrapper.children;
const array = Array.from(elementsWrapper.children);

document.getElementById("bt-add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const newElement = document.createElement("div");
  newElement.textContent = "Added later";
  elementsWrapper.appendChild(newElement);
});
document.getElementById("bt-log").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("collection.length:", collection.length);
  console.log("array.length:", array.length);
});
```

```html
<button id="bt-add">Add new element</button>
<button id="bt-log">Log <code>.length</code></button>

<p>
  Try logging first! Then try to add elements, and log again! See the difference?
</p>

<div>Elements:</div>
<div id="elements">
  <div>Initially existent</div>
  <div>Initially existent</div>
</div>
```

### Alternative way of hiding

Here are ways of hiding the elements:

- Use [inline styling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) (this is what you did!).
- Use CSS classes.
- Use the HTML [attribute `hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden).

For small style changes I too would use inline styling. But for only hiding elements I would use the `hidden` attribute.

Also, there are multiple CSS ways of hiding elements:

- Using `display: none`: Will hide the element as if it doesn't exist.
- Using `opacity: 0`: Will hide the element by making it invisible; it still takes up space, and should still be part of the [accessibility tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Accessibility_tree) (opinionated).
- Moving it off-site with `position: fixed` and `top`, `left`, etc. properties: (Please don't.)
  Will move the element off-site, visually. It will still be part of the accessibility tree, and will only work for languages with the intended writing direction (e.g. it won't work for [right-to-left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/rtl) languages).
- Setting `width`, `height`, `margin`, `padding` and `border` to 0: Will hide the element only visually; it will still be part of the accessibility tree, and will stop [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). [Screen-reader only classes](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) use this for non-visual elements, very useful.

Comment: Your section on "Variable lifetimes" is very misleading. Closures eliminate the need for a global variable.

Comment: @Andy Nowhere am I talking about the global context specifically, though I do see how my wording may seem confusing. Feel free to edit that section.